# PhpWord TemplateProcessor clone table rows and insert information in them

Tags: laravel, invoice, phpword, phpoffice

I have a issue with the phpword tables.

[image: Table structure]

I have the following table and I want to clone the first table row and replace the information in it. So far I have no progress. I've used `getVariables()` method to get all the variables from the document and loop through them. I've checked if the value is array and If it is it belongs to the row. I have structured the data in the following way

```
Collection {#971 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    "ticket_id" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 7
      0 => 6
    ]
    "ticket_number" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "157-12313121321"
      1 => null
    ]
    "price_offered_bgn" => array:2 [▼
      0 => 978.0
      1 => 196.0
    ]
    "ticket_is" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Requested"
    ]
    "departure_date" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "2020-10-20 00:00:00"
      1 => "2020-01-29 00:00:00"
    ]
    "return_date" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "2020-10-29 00:00:00"
      1 => null
    ]
    "company_address" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "ADDRESS"
    ]
    "company_bulstat" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "company_dds_number" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "BG 104023232353"
    ]
    "mol" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Gleichner"
    ]
    "first_name" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Araceli"
      1 => "Francisca"
    ]
    "last_name" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Gleichner"
      1 => "Schmitt"
    ]
  ]
}
```

After I tried to clone the variables and insert the values I came up with the following result

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "TICKET_NUMBER"
  1 => "FIRST_NAME"
  2 => "LAST_NAME"
  3 => "DEPARTURE_DATE"
]
array:9 [▼
  0 => "FIRST_NAME#1"
  1 => "LAST_NAME#1"
  2 => "DEPARTURE_DATE#1"
  3 => "RETURN_DATE#1"
  4 => "TICKET_NUMBER#2"
  5 => "FIRST_NAME#2"
  6 => "LAST_NAME#2"
  7 => "DEPARTURE_DATE#2"
  8 => "RETURN_DATE#2"
]
```

And this error
`Can not clone row, template variable not found or variable contains markup.`
`at TemplateProcessor->cloneRow('${FIRST_NAME}', 2)`

I will be very thankful if you give me any ideas how I can clone this row and insert values in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is solved. I've made the table structure like this

```
+-----------+----------------+
| ${row}    | ${Item}        |
|           |                +
|           | ${ItemInfo}    |
+-----------+----------------+
+-----------+----------------+
| ${row#1}  | ${Item}        |
|           |                +
|           | ${ItemInfo}    |
+-----------+----------------+
```

I'm cloning the row with the `cloneRow('ROW', 2)` method 
[PhpWord Docs](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#clonerow) this gives me 2 copies of ROW that I can work with and adds on each one of them `#INDEX`. This way i looped throught them and replaced the **place holder** with the actual value like this

```
 foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
$this->wordFile->setValue(strtoupper($key) . '#' . $index, $value);
$this->wordFile->setValue('ROW#' . $index, $index);
}
```

the `KEY` variable is the field name and then i concatenate the `#INDEX` to it.
**Cloned rows start with index of 1 (#1, #2, #3 and so on...).**

Comment: hi sir can i have ur social media contact. i want to learn about table in template processor.